# How to delete my site not found urls?

Tags: url, sitemap, http-status-code-404

I have website. last two weeks ago I change new media / entertainment related site. old Content is download link provided. Now I get 20000 urls not found. 5000 urls sitemap errors. How to delete this urls. I am tried. I used google webmaster tools. my site losing visitors.

Comment: Please consider reading http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html to help you get better answers to your questions.

Comment: You can’t “delete” a URL. A URL is just the way how the location of a resource can be described. And a 404 response code on a requested URL just means that there is no resource at that location. So what do you want to delete? The location description?

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect the old locations to the new ones, using the [HTTP 301 Moved Permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) status code.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect old url to the new one! This can be done in .htaccess fle:

```
Redirect 301 http://old_url http://new_url
```

Comment: [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) does only work on URL paths.